# how to use a variable from another .ftl in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to use a defined variable in a second template to have the same output in the current one.

template 1:

```
      [#if definition.name=="configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE"]
      [#assign valueMinimalStackSize = definition.value]
      [/#if]
```

Second template:

```
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE      ((uint16_t)${valueMinimalStackSize})
```

how could I have the same output of "valueMinimalStackSize " in the second template please ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could have a template that sets these variables, let's call it `"commons.ftl"`, and then use `<#include "commons.ftl">` at the beginning of other templates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually tested it but not working. I still having exception as the variable is evaluated as null

Comment: Well, it has to work, it's a basic feature of FreeMarker. Can you give a minimal but reasonably complete example of what you tried?

Comment: Oh, if you are using square bracket tag syntax, as in your question, then it's `[#include "commons.ftl"]` of course.